# odata and CamelCase

Tags: javascript, json, odata, camelcasing

Faced with the problem of OData get JSON accordingly style Model EF.

```
{
   Name: "..",
   Number: 123
}
```

According to information on the Internet set CamelCase in WebAPI do line

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

In OData line not worked.

How in OData set in return JSON CamelCase?
OR
How in Client convert complex JSON в JSON with field CamelСase?

Comment: I wonder if posting the question in Russian will actually help as this is a English speaking site..

Comment: These don't appear to be CamelCase issues - do you have a same where CamelCase would actually apply? Do you have a sample of it working without the CamelCase - and then layering in camel case to show it breaks?

Comment: ember.js components required field property json CamelCase {{input value=name}} otherwise not worked.

Answer (score 1):

OData itself supports CamelCase, and this sample may help you:http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataCamelCaseSample/

Comment: Little problem. using System.Web.OData.Builder and Microsoft.OData.Edm; i have using System.Web.Http.OData and System.Web.Http.OData.Builder; What's the difference libraries?

Comment: System.Web.OData.dll is for OData v4, and System.Web.Http.OData.dll is for Odata v3. OData v4 is a standard of OASIS, but v3 is not.